# How to create a regex for adding single line valid ssh-key

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently in my application users are able to add multi-line ssh-keys in a field. Also user can paste as many ssh-keys as they want in that field. Right now I have the following regex for this behavior:

```
const publicSshKeyRegex = /^(ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2|ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNT|ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAzODQAAAAIbmlzdHAzOD|ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHA1MjEAAAAIbmlzdHA1Mj|ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5|ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3)[0-9A-Za-z+/]+[=]{0,3}(\s.*)?(\n|$)/;
```

But now what I want is that not to allow users to add multi-line ssh-keys and not to allow them to add several ssh-keys. It means that user will be able to add only one ssh-key and it should be in a single line.
So the expected behavior would be To add only one ssh-key, single line.

Could anyone help me to create a new regex for new expecting behavior?

Comment: You can match a single line removing the `\s.*` as `\s` can also match a newline. As the `=` seems optional, you can match the character class before 1 times and add `.*` to match the rest of the line. `^(?:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2|ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNT|ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAzODQAAAAIbmlzdHAzOD|ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHA1MjEAAAAIbmlzdHA1Mj|ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5|ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3)[0-9A-Za-z+/].*$` https://regex101.com/r/SQcN67/1

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot. what is the purpose of `?:` this? What it does here?

Comment: The `(?:....)` is a non capture group for the alternatives `|`. As you want a match only, you don't need the capture group `()` for after processing. Did it work out?

Comment: Yes, it's working perfectly as per my requirements. I just want to add one more condition. user may have an extra new line end of the ssh-key they have pasted. So if there is one new line after the ssh-key it will be consider as a valid ssh-key. What should I change in your regex for that?

Comment: Tty it like this with an optional newline at the end https://regex101.com/r/DJRPIt/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part in the pattern `(\s.*)?` optionally matches a whitespace char (that can also match a newline) followed by the rest of the string, allowing for 2 lines to be matched.

If you want a single line only, you can omit that part, and add `.*` to match the rest of the line, followed by an optional newline and assert the end of the string.

Doing so, this is part `[=]{0,3}` becomes optional and the character class `[0-9A-Za-z+/]+` can be shortened to match at least a single character.

```
^(?:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2|ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNT|ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAzODQAAAAIbmlzdHAzOD|ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHA1MjEAAAAIbmlzdHA1Mj|ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5|ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3)[0-9A-Za-z+/].*\n?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4RHGSF/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2|ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNT|ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAzODQAAAAIbmlzdHAzOD|ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHA1MjEAAAAIbmlzdHA1Mj|ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5|ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3)[0-9A-Za-z+/].*\n?$/;
[
  "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2a",
  "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2a\n",
  "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2a\ntest\n"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```